# Need help with starting proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not sure what to do here. I am not even comfortable with the general procedure to do these type of proofs...

I try to prove:

> $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L,\ L\in(a,b)\Rightarrow \exists n_o\in\mathbb{N},\ \forall n>n_0,\ x_n\in(a,b)$

I know the following:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=L\iff \forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N},\ s.t.\ \forall n>N,\ |x_n-L|<\epsilon$$

What I **think** I need to find is $\exists N'\in\mathbb{N}\ s.t.\ \forall n>N',\ a<x_n<b$, but I don't know how to use what I have to get what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose $\epsilon = \min\{|L - a|, |L - b|\} > 0$ (why is this positive?) then there is an $N$ associated such that

$$n \ge N \implies |x_n - L| < \epsilon$$

Now by our choice of $\epsilon$, it follows that $a < L < b$ as desired.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why we choose that $N(\epsilon)$...

Comment: @agent154 Because if $n \ge N$, then $|x_n - L| < \epsilon = \min(|L - a|, |L - b|)$. Do you see how this implies that $a < x_n < b$?

Comment: I think so, not sure.

Comment: OK, I think I see it now - $b-L$ gives the distance between $L$ and $b$, likewise for $L-a$... So the minimum of the two is guaranteed to be within the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Is there any way to derive a value for $n_0$ from this $\epsilon$? I'm assuming not since we don't know (or care) what $x_n$ is... I'm just wondering if it's sufficient to say "Let $\epsilon=\min(L-a,b-L)$. Therefore, $\exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N},\ \forall n>n_{0},\ |x_n|<\min(L-a,b-L)$."

Comment: That should read "$\exists n_{0}\in\mathbb{N},\ \forall n>n_{0},\ \epsilon<x_n<2\epsilon$."

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Put $\varepsilon := \min\{b-L, L-a\}$.